# Unity. How to prevent VS Code stop on UnityEngine.ExitGUIException?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, exception, debugging

Unity ver 2022.3.0. Visual Studio Code ver 1.77.0

VS Code is attached to Unity as a debugger.

Each time when I press Add Component button to any game object in the scene -- ExitGUIException is raised so VS Code becomes active and Unity pauses. So I can't add components unless I stop debugging.

As you can see on the screenshot -- Unity editor, not my scripts caused the exception, so I can't fix it. I tried to add an exception to the ignored list (bottom of the screenshot) -- but this not helps.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: other than i have no idea how you broke it in enough that adding a component of button causes unity to break - only thing i can guess is you named something the same as part of the button component.  But, does pause on error change its behavior as my unity errors dont throw me into my editor